# Flex 4.5 Tree component

Tags: tree, flex4.5, spark-skinning

- How to add vertical distance between tree header & 1st node of that?
- How to set the background color of node' label when that node is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an easy way to add vertical distance between tree header and first node.  It would be possible through making a customer [TreeItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/treeClasses/TreeItemRenderer.html) and just adding a gap at the top.

To change the background color of a node when it is selected you can use

```
myTree.setStyle( "selectionColor", 0x0000FF );
```

or declared in the mxml as a property of the control

```
<mx:Tree selectionColor="0x0000FF" />
```